# I want to generate a new column in a pandas dataframe, counting "edges" in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

i have a dataframe looking like this:

```
A B....X
1 1    A
2 2    B
3 3    A
4 6    K
5 7    B
6 8    L
7 9    M
8 1    N
9 7    B
1 6    A
7 7    A
```

that is, some "rising edges" occur from time to time in the column X (in this example the edge is x==B)
What I need is, a new column Y which increments every time a value of B occurs in X:

```
A B....X  Y
1 1    A  0
2 2    B  1
3 3    A  1
4 6    K  1
5 7    B  2
6 8    L  2
7 9    M  2
8 1    N  2
9 7    B  3
1 6    A  3
7 7    A  3
```

In SQL I would use some trick like `sum(case when x=B then 1 else 0) over ... rows between first and previous`. How can I do it in Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cumsum`

```
df['Y'] = (df.X == 'B').cumsum()

Out[8]:
    A  B  X  Y
0   1  1  A  0
1   2  2  B  1
2   3  3  A  1
3   4  6  K  1
4   5  7  B  2
5   6  8  L  2
6   7  9  M  2
7   8  1  N  2
8   9  7  B  3
9   1  6  A  3
10  7  7  A  3
```

Comment: @don_alberto: you are welcome. Glad I could help :)